# New language in voice recognition

Tags: mobile, voice-recognition, voice

I am interesting in voice recognition applications and algorithms but actually didn't use them for development yet.

I have a several questions and will appreciate your advice.

I think I need to know:
What kind of open source softwares are available now? (does the Google's voice search program uses any open source voice recognition soft?).
Whether the existing voce recognition softwares, even paid, provide an interface for adding a new language to be recognized?

(it is prefferable for me to find/use libraries which could be addapted into a mobile application)

If you think that it would be better to know something else also, please let me know!!

Thank you all very much.
Arsen

Comment: Hello Arsen. Questions to find or recommend a tool are not welcome on stackoverflow, see http://stackoverflow.com/tour. To create support for your language you can use CMUSphinx http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net, specifically see the tutorial http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam

Comment: Hello Nikolay. Thank you for your comment. So in that case may be it will be good to close/delete the question till I will have more time to rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

to add an new language, you must make your own tts and stt. Without them, speech recognition is not possible. Its way too complicated to create a text to speech for an new language. Just Google for your language and surely you will find a tts. Or just proceed with making one. :P

Comment: Yes, I imagine how difficult it could be. But anyway. Thank you for your response.